# How to pass model(bean) value using ModelAndview from controller to jsp page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am creating Spring mvc login application, so while registration or login I am simply getting ${attributename} (in my case ${firstname}) without actual attribute value in welcome jsp. Kindly let me know whats the problem with my code.
Userbean and welcome jsp has same attibute name.

**LoginController**:

```
    @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping ("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject("login",new Login());
        return mav;

    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/loginProcess")
    public ModelAndView loginProcess(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login){
         ModelAndView mav = null;
        User user = userService.validateUser(login);
        if(user!=null){
            mav= new ModelAndView("welcome");
            System.out.println("user.getFirstname(): "+user.getFirstname());             
            mav.addObject("firstname", user.getFirstname());
            //model.addAttribute("firstname", "welcome"+user.getFirstname());


        }
        else

            mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject("error", "Username or password is wrong");
        return mav;


    }

}
```

login jsp:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form id="loginForm" modelAttribute="login" action="loginProcess" method="post">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form:label path="username">Username: </form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:input path="username" name="username" id="username" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:password path="password" name="password" id="password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <form:button id="login" name="login">Login</form:button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="home.jsp">Home</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>

             <td style="font-style: italic; color: red;">${param.message}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> ${firstname}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="home.jsp">Home</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**userbean:**

```
public class User {

      private String username;
      private String password;
      private String firstname;
      private String lastname;
      private String email;
      private String address;
      private int phone;
 //getter, setter
}
```

Comment: In the code of your controller, the if else part is not correct in syntax, Can you check that? and also surround your td values with double quotes.

Comment: It looks okay to me. Two notes: JSP is not the best choice for new projects (Thymeleaf is much easier to test and work with), and reinventing login logic is not the best option if you can use Spring Security to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please modify this in your jsp page?

```
    <tr>
        <td> "${firstname}"</td>
    </tr>
```

Just added double quotes. Also add

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

this to your JSP file.

Comment: Thank you, but no luck now I am getting "${firstname}" in welcome jsp

Comment: Can you add this in your JSP page and see <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> and also please test with both double quotes and without double quotes

Comment: Updated the answer!!, Can you please mark it correct - @Priya